# How to scrape season episode numbers from tvdb

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am attempting to isolate and work with total season episode numbers from the tvdb. Just as an easy example im working with the show LEGION (https://www.thetvdb.com/series/legion). This main page will display how many seasons the show has and at the end of the row, there is a badge indicating the number of episodes in each season. I am wanting an "absolute number" of episodes for a show, so I need all these numbers added together. This I am able to do, however I want to exclude the "specials" season episode number, which is the hard part. Especially since the inner text of these elements will display the badge value before indicating the season it is referencing.

I have gone through a few stages.
First I was able to get the inner text of the parent tag which gives me a block of info stating everything in the table as follows (There seems to be 2 tags with the same class name which is why im getting double results. Any help with that would be appreciated too)

Specials 
April 2018 - April 2018 
8

Season 1 
February 2017 - March 2017 
11

Season 2 
April 2018 - June 2018 
8

Season 3 
June 2019 - August 2019

All Seasons

1 
Specials 
April 2018 - April 2018

8 
Season 1 
February 2017 - March 2017

11 
Season 2 
April 2018 - June 2018

8 
Season 3 
June 2019 - August 2019

All Seasons

Second I was able to isolate one block at a time by looping through all elements in the parent tag as follows

1 
Specials 
April 2018 - April 2018

Third I have gotten to the stage where I can loop through again and isolate just the number located in the badge (I say badge as that is how it is referenced in the html code)

I also back tracked and worked with stage 2 and placed a regex function in to identify the word "specials" but was unable to figure out how to skip that and continue with in the running for loop.

I believe I may need to be working with parent, children, sibling coding to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub()

Dim XML_05 As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTML_05 As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XML_05.Open "GET", "https://www.thetvdb.com/series/legion", False
XML_05.send
HTML_05.body.innerHTML = XML_05.responseText

Dim NETC_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim NET_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim REO_05 As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim MO_05 As Object
Dim SeasonsList As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim SeasonsInfo As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim SI_05 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Badge As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


Set SeasonsList = HTML_05.getElementsByClassName("hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg")

For Each SeasonsInfo In SeasonsList
    Debug.Print SeasonsList.Length
        For Each SI_05 In SeasonsInfo.getElementsByTagName("li")
                    For Each Badge In SI_05.Children
                    Debug.Print Badge.innerText
                Next Badge
        Next SI_05
Next SeasonsInfo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Specials` is first and `All Seasons` is last so you can loop a `nodeList` from `1` to `nodeList.Length-2` to avoid those two nodes and simply sum the numbers in between. I use a surrogate HTMLDocument variable to hold each node's html so I can leverage `querySelector` again and avoid long chains via `getElements` and `nextSibling` etc. I wasn't really sure if you wanted the other info as well at some point so I stored each season name, dates and episode count in an array `results` (excluding nodes as described). This method also means code complexity is reduced to a single loop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTotalEpisodes()
    Dim i As Long, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, seasons As Object, results(), r As Long

    Set html = New HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.thetvdb.com/series/legion", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set seasons = html.querySelectorAll(".hidden-xs .list-group-item")
    ReDim results(1 To seasons.Length - 2, 1 To 3)

    For i = 1 To seasons.Length - 2
        html2.body.innerHTML = seasons.item(i).outerHTML
        results(i, 1) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".list-group-item-heading").innerText)
        results(i, 2) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".list-group-item-text").innerText)
        results(i, 3) = 1 * html2.querySelector(".badge").innerText
    Next
    Debug.Print Application.Sum(Application.index(results, 0, 3))
End Sub
```

---

If you wanted to store all info including first and last node but still perform a conditional sum you could house titles to exclude in an array and check against that during loop; only sum if current header not in array of exclusions

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTotalEpisodes()
    Dim i As Long, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, seasons As Object, results(), r As Long
    Dim exclusions(), heading As String, badge As Long, total As Long

    Set html = New HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
    exclusions = Array("Specials", "All Seasons")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.thetvdb.com/series/legion", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set seasons = html.querySelectorAll(".hidden-xs .list-group-item")
    ReDim results(1 To seasons.Length, 1 To 3)

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To seasons.Length - 1
        html2.body.innerHTML = seasons.item(i).outerHTML
        heading = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".list-group-item-heading").innerText)
        badge = 1 * html2.querySelector(".badge").innerText
        results(i + 1, 1) = html2.querySelector(".list-group-item-heading").innerText
        results(i + 1, 2) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".list-group-item-text").innerText)
        results(i + 1, 3) = badge
        If IsError(Application.match(heading, exclusions, 0)) Then
            total = total + badge
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print total
End Sub
```

---

OP questions:

1. [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) - forces variable declaration.

> When Option Explicit On or Option Explicit appears in a file, you must
>   explicitly declare all variables by using the Dim or ReDim statements.
>   If you try to use an undeclared variable name, an error occurs at
>   compile time. The Option Explicit Off statement allows implicit
>   declaration of variables.

It's best practice and useful for catching typos as well.

2. `results()` - I am declaring a [dynamic array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays) meaning I don't yet know the required dimensions but will later ReDim when I do. It is in fact results() As Variant (implicitly). See also [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm). I can ReDim later because at this point

   Set seasons = html.querySelectorAll(".hidden-xs .list-group-item")

`seasons.Length` will give me the number of rows for the first dimension of `results()`.

3. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL) - is akin to `getElementsBy`. It applies a [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (or combination) to [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) (e.g. `ie.Document`).

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
>   NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
>   specified group of selectors

Modern browsers are optimized for css so this generally a fast and flexible method of finding nodes.

4. `Trim$` - is typed version of `Trim`. It is used to remove the surplus leading/trailing whitespace from the `node.innerText`.
5. The bottom version should work for single seasons. Simply alter the array `exclusions` to account for what you wish to include/exclude. If it doesn't please provide me an example and I will update for you.

Comment: Thanks for the further assistance QHArr. Youre a machine. Looking into this now.

Comment: Any questions please ask away :-)

Comment: Yeah I have a few.Just wondering how the option explicit works and why it is needed, when you are setting dimensions for variables, you write results() but its not set as anything. I see that it is redimensioned further down though. Can you explain or point me in the direction to learn about the queryselectorall . I have kind of put together what is happening in the redim results brackets, but unsure as to how it works, also unsure about how the trim function works with the query selector in relation to the node in the HTML2 document

Comment: I know it seems like im asking about the whole thing haha. I see why it works and I have put together enough to adjust the code to exclude the latest season and count everything else. Im just wanting a better understanding of how the parts work. I have to do some more tweaking as ive just found out the above code will only work for multiple seasons. not single ones. I think it may be due to the set "window" that excludes the specials and the -2 for the end. If there are 2 or less nodes I think that would cause a problem.

Comment: It is absolutely fine. I am busy with work at moment but will update answer to address each point later today and drop you a line so you know. Then have a look and come back with any further questions.

Comment: Sorry QHarr, my follow up question is most likely asked here. The issue im having is the site code was changed, throwing a spanner in the works, mainly because I do not have access to the old HTML code to compare and figure the new one out. Your code should still work but im having trouble identifying the correct elements using the query selector. I think im having trouble with the syntax. I can get a return using the element IDs with a space in a certain  area but removing the space returns 0 results. I feel like im close but am stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Also is there a way to post code in the comments or do I need to post an answer for you to see what im trying to do

Comment: you have enough rep to open a chat room Ithink  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and add me as write access

Comment: Hey qharr, I can't for the life of me find the create room button. I've checked my rep and it says I'm allowed but can't seem to find the actual "new" button.

Comment: It’s at the bottom of the page of the link I shared

Comment: Might be an issue through android. The only button I see down the bottom is show frozen rooms. I'll check on my pc when I get home.

Comment: Hey Qharr, Apologies for the lack of response. Was out of town for work on short notice. Tried the chat link but cant be found it says.

Comment: The room was deleted due to inactivity

Comment: I can open a new one but having a day off today (mostly)

Comment: ah sorry man. No rush. Im working this week too. off on the weekend. Ill shoot a message then and see if youre free.